# Writing a trigger to update a column when a different row is updated

Tags: sql, triggers

I have a table, "person" that represents parents and children (There are really more columns and names are not actually named this way, but the rest of the information and accuracy is not pertinent).

1. column1 = ID
2. column2 = parentID
3. column3 = active

column2 is a reference to the ID of column1 in another row.

1. If a row contains a value in column2, it is a child.
2. If a row contains NULL in column2, it is a parent.

Column3 is a CHAR(1) which is used for determining if the person is active. A child cannot be active if the parent is not.

1. Column3 can contain 'y' or 'n'

I need to write a trigger that updates a child row column 3 when its' parent is updated to 'n' for column 3.

For example,

1. If row1 has a value of 'Y' for column3, its children can have 'y' OR 'N'.
2. If row1 has a value of 'N' for column3, its children must be updated to have column 3 = 'N'.

Can anyone assist with the logic behind doing this? I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

Comment: Please specify what DBMS you are using.

Comment: Sorry! Forgot about that. Question has been edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When using an update trigger, the 'inserted' table is the result of the update.  In this situation you need to:

- look for an update to a parent and check if they are are inactive
- join the parent to its children
- update the children to be inactive

Here is a quick example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger ON person
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE child
    FROM inserted parent
         INNER JOIN person child ON child.ParentID = parent.ID
    SET child.active = 'n'
    WHERE parent.active = 'n'

GO
```

I hope this helps!